# Embed Live Streaming From Facebook Page When They Start Streaming

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming, live-streaming, facebook-page

I am trying to know how get just the live video stream from a facebook page. In my case, I want to build an app to my church and I need just their live stream. On their facebook page are a lot of videos that was streamed, but I'm not interested that, I want just their live stream.

Problem: I don't know when they start streaming and I don't know how get it, I'd like to have just the streaming video that they start streaming.

Someon can help me with that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/live_videos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC you also asked this question in the FB Dev group and added the info that you do not have access to those pages. W/o access to them or having admin users granting your app access to them you cannot retrieve notifications/callbacks whenever a broadcast starts. Even when just polling them (using the endpoint CBroe mentioned) you need a page access token to do so.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that.